# Microsoft Lync chat bot

Tags: lync, chatbot

I would like to write a Microsoft Lync chat bot. The bot should be searchable on lync similar to facebook bots. Any ideas or pointers would be helpful. Microsoft bot framework is available on office 365 teams but is completely silent on Lync.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use UCMA to build a Lync bot and then use the DirectLine API to connect it to the Bot framework.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Bot Builder Framework doesn't support Lync as a channel: 
[Connect a bot to channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

For your case, you'll have to use the Microsoft Unified Communications Managed API instead of the Bot Builder Framework: [Creating a Lync bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/ucma-sdk/creating-a-lync-bot)